# Eigenvectors for an eigenvalue of $0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Without calculation, find one eigenvalue and two linearly independent eigenvectors of $A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 && 2 && 2 \\ 2 && 2 && 2 \\ 2 && 2 && 2 \end{bmatrix} $.

This matrix is non-invertible because its columns are linearly dependent. So the number $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $0$ are solutions of $Ax=0$ and therefore have entries that produce a linear independence relation among the columns of A. Any nonzero vector in ($\Bbb R^3$) whose entries sum to $0$ will work. Find any two vectors that are not multiples; for instance,

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix} $ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $.

I do not understand how the first vector is obtained.

So far I've done.

$ \sim \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 && 1 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 \end{bmatrix} $

$\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -x_2-x_3 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} = x_2\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + x_3\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

How do you obtain $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix} $?

Why is it that any nonzero vector in ($\Bbb R^3$) whose entries sum to $0$ will work?

Comment: "*why is it that any nonzero vector whose entries sum to $0$ will work?*" Try multiplying such a vector to it and see what happens.  Since all entries in $A$ are equal, you could simply factor out a common $2$.  "*how do you obtain...*" By setting $x_2=1$ and $x_3=-2$, your two vectors you found add up to the vector in question.  Since it was stated to do this *without calculation*, several answers are possible.  Your two vectors for example are also correct answers.

Comment: Why must the entries sum to $0$?

Comment: "Without calculation"? That's impossible. Maybe they mean "without explicitly solving the characteristic polynomial and following matrix equation systems".

Comment: @mathreadler, no calculation is necessary to find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of any multiple of the $Ones$ matrix beyond simple addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Why must the entries sum to $0$*"

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}&a_{1,3}\\ a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}&a_{2,3}\\a_{3,1}&a_{3,2}&a_{3,3}\end{bmatrix}$ and $x = \begin{bmatrix} x_{1}\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$

By **definition** of matrix product, you have

$Ax = \begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1}x_1 + a_{1,2}x_2 + a_{1,3}x_3\\a_{2,1}x_1 + a_{2,2}x_2 + a_{2,3}x_3\\a_{3,1}x_1 + a_{3,2}x_2 + a_{3,3}x_3\end{bmatrix}$

Note what happens when all entries of $A$ are identical and nonzero:

$\dots = \begin{bmatrix} a(x_1+x_2+x_3)\\a(x_1+x_2+x_3)\\a(x_1+x_2+x_3)\end{bmatrix} = a\begin{bmatrix}x_1+x_2+x_3\\x_1+x_2+x_3\\x_1+x_2+x_3\end{bmatrix}$

If this were to equal the zero vector (which is implied since these are eigenvectors for the eigenvalue of zero) then that means that every entry above must be zero.  That is exactly the same as saying that $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$

On the other hand, supposing that $x_1+x_2+x_3=k\neq 0$, you would have $Ax = a\begin{bmatrix}k\\k\\k\end{bmatrix}\neq \overrightarrow{0}=0x$ and so $x$ would not be an eigenvector for the eigenvalue of zero.

In general, any nonzero multiple of the $Ones_{n\times n}$ matrix, say $a\cdot Ones_{n\times n}$ (matrix where all entries are $a$) will have an eigenvalue of zero and every eigenvector for zero will satisfy the relation that the sum of the entries is zero.  We know that there are no others by a rank-nullity argument and that the remaining eigenvalue is equal to the trace (sum of the diagonal).

Furthermore, the other eigenvalue will necessarily be $a\cdot n$ with eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\\vdots\\1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Why does it matter that the entries must sum to $0$ when $\lambda x = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $ due to lambda being $0$?

Comment: @user1766555 Suppose that they didn't sum to zero, but instead summed to $k$.  Then going through the matrix multiplication, you see that $Ax = \begin{bmatrix}2k\\2k\\2k\end{bmatrix}\neq \overrightarrow{0}=0x$.  This could also be seen directly from a rank-nullity argument and theorems about eigenvalues (namely that the sum of the eigenvalues must be equal to the sum of the diagonal).

Comment: So due to $Ax = \begin{bmatrix}2k\\2k\\2k\end{bmatrix}\neq \overrightarrow{0}$, that also means $Ax \neq \lambda x $?

Comment: @user1766555 Specifically for the eigenvalue $\lambda=0$, yes.  The only way for two vectors to be equal is if all entries are equal.  The only way two real numbers multiplied together equals zero is if at least one of them is zero, but we said that $k\neq 0$ and $2\neq 0$, so $2k\neq 0$.  As mentioned in my edit, there will be another eigenvector which does not have the property that the entries sum to zero, but this will be for a different eigenvalue.

Comment: But it is not "without calculation". You must perform calculations to confirm that you are dealing with a multiple of the Ones matrix. Just because those calculations are done automatically in your head does not mean they do not occur.

Comment: @JMoravitz Excellent answer, but I think it would've been much clearer if you stopped your reasoning at the conclusion that the vector entries must sum to zero. The rest of the stuff that followed was unnecessary and in fact confused me.

Comment: @aleksandrh most times the question is asked it is to find *all* eigenvectors and eigenvalues at which point the remainder of the post was in fact necessary.  Although unnecessary for the exact wording of the OP's question, it is for the all too common extension on the problem which is often either asked as a followup or is just a curiosity question that naturally occurs.  What in particular confused you?  My notation for the matrix of all ones?  That the trace equals the sum of the eigenvalues?  That the eigenvalue zero has multiplicity n-1?

Comment: The part with the Ks, $k\ne0$, made sense. But the rest of it was a bit confusing, the parts with the identity matrices

Comment: @AleksandrH The identity matrix did not appear even once in the entirety of my post.  Given a specific example, $\begin{bmatrix}2&2&2\\2&2&2\\2&2&2\end{bmatrix}$ has the eigenvalue $0$ with multiplicity two with corresponding eigenbasis $\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ (*or any other two linearly independent vectors in the eigenspace*) as well as the eigenvalue $6$ with corresponding eigenbasis $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Do not confuse $Ones_{3\times 3}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$ with $I_{3\times 3}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$.  The first half of the post was discussing how to find $0$ as an eigenvalue and how to find and describe an eigenbasis for $0$.  The second half of the post was showing that there is an additional eigenvalue different than zero.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, I confused Ones with I